# Enumeration of quadrangulations with a boundary and simple faces.

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

I wish to enumerate all quadrangulations of a $2p$ gon with $n$ internal vertices.  Quadrangles are required to have simple faces. Simple face means all four vertices of each quadrangle are distinct.

Is anything known about this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of subtly different definitions out there.  The following two papers enumerate types of quadrangulations of a disk, but I didn't check if the type you are interested in is included:

W. G. Brown, Enumeration of quadrangular dissections of the disk, Canad. J.
Math., 17 (1965) 302-317.

R. C. Mullin and P. J. Schellenberg, The enumeration of c-nets via quadrangulations,
J. Combinatorial Theory, 4 (1968) 259-276.